# Cannot push to github because of large files

Tags: html, git, github, version-control

I am getting this error shown in the screenshot below when I try to push to Github.

I have removed any video files that were added in the previous commit using the 'git rm --cached ' command, however it is still complaining about video files begin too large, even though I have removed them from the commit... please help!

I have tried to add the mp4 files to my git attributes file so that they will be stored in Git Large File Storage, but still no joy.

I am relatively new to git and the git process but I have never had this problem when pushing files. Please help me as I cannot push anything up to github, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Show us how you used `git rm --cached`

Comment: `git rm --cached 'vid/drone_footage.mp4'`                                             
`rm 'vid/drone_footage.mp4'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git filter-branch` command in-order to remove a big file which is wrongly committed in git

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to remove the bigger files from Git history so that they are not pushed, but not from the file system.

If you mistakenly push the file in your previous commit, you can do:

```
git rm --cached giant_file  # Stage our giant file for removal, but leave it on disk

git commit --amend -CHEAD # Amend the previous commit with your change

git push # Push our rewritten, smaller commit
```

If not, they recommend using [BFG – repo cleaner tool](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) for cleaning up repositories:

```
bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M #removes files above 1 MB
```